# Mocking constant with Jest not working (Multiple mocks in same test file)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, mocking, react-testing-library

The problem I am having is that the mocked constant does not change in the component after `jest.doMock`.

Take a look at the [minimal repo](https://github.com/StianIsmar/minimal_repo_jest).

I have tried with `mock` instead of `doMock`- same error.

**App.test.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import App from './App'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

describe('testing app.js', () => {

  // To reset manually mocked values
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
  });

  test("SET CONSTANT TO 1", () => {
    jest.doMock('./myConstants.js', () => ({
      CONSTANT: {
        NUMBER: 1
      }
    }))
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument()

  })

  test("SET CONSTANT TO 3", () => {
    jest.doMock('./myConstants.js', () => ({
      CONSTANT: {
        NUMBER: 3
      }
    }))
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText('3')).toBeInTheDocument()

  })
})
```

**App.js**

```js
import React from "react"
import { CONSTANT } from './myConstants.js'

console.log(CONSTANT)

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      {CONSTANT.NUMBER}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

**myConstants.js**:

```js
export const CONSTANT = { NUMBER: 2 }
```

Both of the tests above fail. The output from one of them is:

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: 3. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          2
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

      29 |     }))
      30 |     const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    > 31 |     expect(getByText('3')).toBeInTheDocument()
```

### Extended solution

Although the provided solution worked perfectly, I did not want to rewrite each component I was going to test (by adding `require(...)`). A workaround was to use `import("./App").then((module)`

```
import React from "react"
import App from './App'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

describe('testing app.js', () => {

  // To reset manually mocked values
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
  });

  jest.doMock('./myConstants.js', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      CONSTANT: {
        NUMBER: 1
      }
    }
  })

  test("SET CONSTANT TO 1", () => {


    // Wait for mock done
    return import('./myConstants.js').then((constants) => {
      console.log(constants.CONSTANT.NUMBER)
      expect(constants.CONSTANT.NUMBER).toBe(1)
      import("./App").then((module) => {
        const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<module.default />)
        expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument()
      })
    })
  })
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `jest.doMock` is quite complicated than you thought. Basically it requires you do a few steps as described https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options.

Which means you have to change your test to meet above requirements as:

```js
test("SET CONSTANT TO 1", () => {
  jest.doMock('./myConstants.js', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      CONSTANT: {
        NUMBER: 1
      }
    }
  })
  
  // Wait for mock done
  return import('./myConstants.js').then(() => {
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument()  
  })
})

// While you also require your code right before using instead of `require` at the top level:

const App = () => {
  // Require to use it right before using it
  const { CONSTANT } = require('./myConstants.js');

  return (
    <div>
      {CONSTANT.NUMBER}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it better to just use `jest.mock` then?

Comment: Yeah. If your module is quite static like this case (the `CONSTANT` is fixed all the time), we can go for that. But if the module contains methods which returns dynamically, you could just use `jest.spyOn` to just mock the single method which isn't required to be implemented at the root level (the same scope with `import`)

Comment: Ok. If I change out doMock with mock, it will be the same setup as above (haven't tried yet)?

Comment: If you change to `jest.mock`, you have to do it at the same scope with `import` meaning put it at the top level, then your `CONSTANT` is fixed which means you won't be able to test 2 cases like your test (Just one test to cover the situation). You get me, right?

Comment: So I am actually inclined to change App.js to `require` the constant right before use (using `jest.doMock`)? Is there a way I can just import it at the top level?

Comment: Looks like I have another idea for you

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing we could also mutate the mocked value directly by still using `jest.mock` as following:

```js
import React from "react"
import App from './App'
import '@testing-library/jest-dom'
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { CONSTANT} from "./myConstants";

jest.mock('./myConstants.js', () => ({
  CONSTANT: {
    NUMBER: 0,
  }
}))

describe('testing app.js', () => {

  // To reset manually mocked values
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.resetModules()
  });

  test("SET CONSTANT TO 1", () => {
    // Mutate directly mocked value by setting our desired value
    CONSTANT.NUMBER = 1;
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText('1')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  test("SET CONSTANT TO 3", () => {
    // Likewise we set it as 3
    CONSTANT.NUMBER = 3;
    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<App />)
    expect(getByText('4')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```