# Jest Mock Imported constant in unit test

Tags: javascript, typescript, unit-testing

Writing unit test on piece of code that uses imported boolean constant. Not able to mock the constant value.

1. index.d.ts

   ```
   export const SOMETHING_OVERWRITE: boolean;
   ```

2 .Mapper.test.ts

```
   it('TEST expected output', () =\> {
   ...
   SOMETHING_OVERWRITE = true;

   ...
   });
```

Getting error :
Cannot assign to 'SOMETHING_OVERWRITE' because it is an import.ts

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to mock or modify the value of an imported constant in a test. Once a constant is imported into a module, it becomes a read-only property of that module and cannot be changed by external code.

You can try something like this:

[Jest - Mock a constant property from a module for a specific test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55137311/jest-mock-a-constant-property-from-a-module-for-a-specific-test)

[Mocking constant with Jest not working (Multiple mocks in same test file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889704/mocking-constant-with-jest-not-working-multiple-mocks-in-same-test-file)

[How to mock an exported const in Jest?](https://thewebdev.info/2022/02/24/how-to-mock-an-exported-const-in-jest/)

In this specific case, if you cannot refactor the code, you may need to consider testing the behavior of the code for both values of **SOMETHING_OVERWRITE**, rather than trying to mock or modify the constant value itself.